# Tabularx expanding over several pages (with multirows)

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, multirow

I have a very long table that expands over several pages. I don't think I can use
the longtable package since the table contains multirows as well

[image]

Here's my attempt:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{tabularx}{340pt}{|x|x|>{\RaggedRight}X|}
\hline

\textbf{Figure} &
  \textbf{Strain} &
  \textbf{Genotype} \\
  \hline
  \hline
  
  \multirow{7}{*}{3.1} &
  N2 &
  wild type \\
 &
  TG2435 &
  vtIs1 V \\
 &
  MDH85 &
  norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]} II;unc-119(ed3)   III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1 \\
 &
  MDH375 &
  nor25 (background: norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]};   II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1) \\
 &
  MDH509 &
  nor104 (background: norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]};   II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1) \\
 &
  MDH514 &
  nor109 (background: norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]};   II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1) \\
 &
  MDH520 &
  nor115 (background: norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]};   II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1) \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{3.3} &
  MDH28 &
  trp-4(ot337);otIs259 \\
 &
  MDH488 &
  cni-1 (tm4274);trp-4(ot337);otIs259{[}dat-1::gfp{]} \\
  \hline
3.4 &
  MDH492 &
  nor25;norEx131{[}cni-1;myo-2::mcherry;rol-6{]}(background:norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1) \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{3.5} &
  MDH496 &
  cni-1(crispr\_nor25);norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]};   II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1 \\
 &
  MDH841 &
  sec-24.2(crispr\_nor104) wt   PAM;norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1 \\
 &
  MDH597 &
  sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus silent   mut{]});norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3)   III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1 \\
 &
  MDH905 &
  cni-1(crispr\_nor140{[}nor115 plus silent   mut{]});norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3)   III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1) \\
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{4.4} &
  MDH590 &
  norEx150{[}pdat::cni-1::UTR, ccRFP{]};   cni-1(crispr\_nor25);norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3)   III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1 \\
 &
  MDH634 &
  norEx177{[}Pdat-1::SEC-24.2::mKate::UTR + ccRFP{]};   sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus silent   mut{]});norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3)   III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1 Line 1 \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{4.7} &
  MDH732 &
  norEx215{[}pdat::sec-24.2(Ex2-4)SENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR +   pdat::sec-24.2(Ex4-2)ANTISENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR + ccRFP{]};   norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1   line 1 \\
 &
  MDH733 &
  norEx216{[}pdat::sec-24.2(Ex2-4)SENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR +   pdat::sec-24.2(Ex4-2)ANTISENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR + ccRFP{]};   norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1   line 2 \\
 &
  MDH719 &
  norEx213{[}pdat::mkate::UTR + ccRFP{]};   norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1   line 1 \\
 &
  MDH720 &
  norEx214{[}pdat::mkate::UTR + ccRFP{]};   norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1   line 2 \\
 &
  MDH739 &
  norEx218{[}pdat::sec-24.2(Ex2-4)SENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR +   pdat::sec-24.2(Ex4-2)ANTISENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR + ccRFP{]};vtIs1 line 1 \\
 &
  MDH740 &
  norEx219{[}pdat::sec-24.2(Ex2-4)SENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR +   pdat::sec-24.2(Ex4-2)ANTISENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR + ccRFP{]};vtIs1 line 2 \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{4.8} &
  MDH570 &
  norEx139{[}Pdat1::cni-1,rol-6,ccRFP{]};trp-4(ot337);otIs259 \\
 &
  MDH675 &
  norEx209{[}Pdat-1::SEC-24.2::mKate::UTR +   ccGFP{]};trp-4(ot337);otIs259, Line 1 \\
 &
  MDH673 &
  norEx207{[}Pdat-1::SEC-24.2::mKate::UTR +   ccGFP{]};norEx139{[}Pdat1::cni-1,rol-6,ccRFP{]};trp-4(ot337);otIs259, Line 2 \\
\hline
4.9 &
  TQ420 &
  trp-4(sy695);XuEx542{[}Ptrp-4::trp-4::yfp + Podr-1::RFP{]} \\
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{4.10, 4.11, 4.12, 4.13} &
  MDH698 &
  norIs1{[}pdat::TRP-4::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx, Line 1 \\
 &
  MDH699 &
  norIs2{[}pdat::TRP-4::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx, Line 2 \\
 &
  MDH705 &
  norIs2{[}pdat::TRP-4::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx;   cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
 &
  MDH742 &
  norIs1{[}pdat::TRP-4::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx;nor104 \\
 &
  MDH707 &
  norIs1{[}pdat::TRP-4::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx;   sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus silent mut{]}) \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{4. 14} &
  PY6100 &
  oyIs59{[}osm-6::osm-6::gfp{]} \\
 &
  MDH886 &
  oyIs59{[}osm-6::osm-6::gfp{]};cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
 &
  MDH887 &
  oyIs59{[}osm-6::osm-6::gfp{]};nor104 \\
 &
  MDH885 &
  oyIs59{[}osm-6::osm-6::gfp{]};sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus   silent mut{]}) \\
\hline
4.15 &
  MDH893 &
  vtIs1{[}dat-1::gfp{]};him-8(e1489); pha-1(e2123) III;   otIs393{[}ift-20p::NLS::tagRFP + pha-1(+){]} \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{4.16} &
  MDH911 &
  Y110A7A.20(ok3191) I;norIs2{[}pdat::TRP-4::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx,   Line 2 \\
 &
  MDH1037 &
  unc-101(sy108) I;norIs1{[}pdat::TRP-4::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{4.18} &
  MDH26 &
  trp-4(ot337);vtIs1 V \\
 &
  MDH938 &
  trp-4(ot337) I;vtIs1;him-8(e1489) IV?;Y110A7A.20(ok3191) I \\
 &
  MDH969 &
  unc-101(sy108) I;trp-4(ot337) I;vtIs1 \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{5.1} &
  MDH932 &
  kyEx576(rol-6+ocr-2::GFP::ocr-2);norIs32{[}Pcni-1::CNI-1::mKate\_HygR;ccGFP{]},   Line 1/xxx \\
 &
  MDH933 &
  kyEx576(rol-6+ocr-2::GFP::ocr-2);norEX180{[}Psec-24.2::SEC-24.2::mKate::UTRsec-24.2   + ccRFP{]} Line 1 \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{5.2, 5.3} &
  CX5448 &
  kyEx576(rol-6+ocr-2::GFP::ocr-2) \\
 &
  MDH903 &
  kyEx576(rol-6+ocr-2::GFP::ocr-2);cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
 &
  MDH904 &
  kyEx576(rol-6+ocr-2::GFP::ocr-2);nor104 \\
 &
  MDH902 &
  kyEx576(rol-6+ocr-2::GFP::ocr-2);sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109   plus silent mut{]}) \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{5.4} &
  MDH936 &
  norIs33{[}Posm-9::OSM-9::GFP +   ccRFP{]}/xxx;norIs32{[}Pcni-1::CNI-1::mKate\_HygR;ccGFP{]}, Line 1/xxx \\
 &
  MDH937 &
  norIs33{[}Posm-9::OSM-9::GFP +   ccRFP{]}/xxx;norEX180{[}Psec-24.2::SEC-24.2::mKate::UTRsec-24.2 + ccRFP{]} Line 1 \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{5.5, 5.6} &
  MDH888 &
  norIs33{[}Posm-9::OSM-9::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx \\
 &
  MDH895 &
  norIs33{[}Posm-9::OSM-9::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx;cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
 &
  MDH897 &
  norIs33{[}Posm-9::OSM-9::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx;nor104 \\
 &
  MDH896 &
  norIs33{[}Posm-9::OSM-9::GFP +   ccRFP{]}/xxx;sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus silent mut{]}); \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{5.7} &
  MDH934 &
  mysIs1{[}PKD2::GFP+ccGFP{]}pkd-2(sy606)IV;him-5(e1490)   V;norIs32{[}Pcni-1::CNI-1::mKate\_HygR;ccGFP{]}, Line 1/xxx \\
 &
  MDH935 &
  mysIs1{[}PKD2::GFP+ccGFP{]}pkd-2(sy606)IV;him-5(e1490)   V;norEX180{[}Psec-24.2::SEC-24.2::mKate::UTRsec-24.2 + ccRFP{]} Line 1 \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{5.8, 5.10} &
  PT443 &
  mysIs1{[}PKD2::GFP+ccGFP{]}pkd-2(sy606)IV;him-5(e1490) V \\
 &
  MDH908 &
  mysIs1{[}PKD2::GFP+ccGFP{]}pkd-2(sy606)IV;cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
 &
  MDH909 &
  mysIs1{[}PKD2::GFP+ccGFP{]}pkd-2(sy606)IV;him-5(e1490)   V;sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus silent mut{]}) \\
 &
  MDH910 &
  mysIs1{[}PKD2::GFP+ccGFP{]}pkd-2(sy606)IV;him-5(e1490) V;nor104 \\
\hline
\multirow{8}{*}{5.11} &
  MDH663 &
  norEx199{[}pdat-1::DAT-1::GFP::UTR + ccRFP{]}, Line 1 \\
 &
  MDH677 &
  norEx210{[}pdat-1::DAT-1::GFP::UTR + ccRFP{]};cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
 &
  MDH757 &
  norEx220{[}Pdat-1::GFP::DAT-1::UTR + ccRFP{]};nor104 \\
 &
  MDH678 &
  norEx211{[}pdat-1::DAT-1::GFP::UTR +   ccRFP{]};sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus silent mut{]}) \\
 &
  MDH666 &
  norEx201{[}Pasic-1::ASIC-1::GFP::UTR+ ccRFP{]}, Line 1 \\
 &
  MDH683 &
  norEx201{[}Pasic-1::ASIC-1::GFP::UTR+ ccRFP{]};cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
 &
  MDH756 &
  norEx201{[}Pasic-1::ASIC-1::GFP::UTR+ ccRFP{]};nor104 \\
 &
  MDH684 &
  norEx201{[}Pasic-1::ASIC-1::GFP::UTR+   ccRFP{]};sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus silent mut{]}) \\
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{5.12} &
  MDH730 &
  zdIs5(I) \\
 &
  MDH241 &
  zdIs5(I);mec-4(u231)(X) \\
 &
  MDH728 &
  zdIs5(I);mec-4(u231)(X);cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
 &
  MDH759 &
  zdIs5(I);mec-4(u231)(X);nor104 \\
 &
  MDH729 &
  zdIs5(I);mec-4(u231)(X);sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus   silent mut{]}) \\
  
  \hline
  
  
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could redesign your table to avoid the use of multirow entirely. With this approach you should be able to use longtable to allow page breaks within your table while at the same time reduci g the amount of unnecessary white space.

Comment: multirow works in longtable  the same as tabular,  you just have to ensure that the page breaks don't happen in the spanned rows.  It is usually best to avoit multirow in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest redesigning your table in order to get rid of all `multirow` commands:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{\quad}l>{\RaggedRight}X}
  \toprule
  Strain &  Genotype \\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \bottomrule
  \endfoot
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 3.1}\\* 
   N2 &
  wild type \\
  TG2435 &
  vtIs1 V \\
  MDH85 &
  norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]} II;unc-119(ed3)   III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1 \\
  MDH375 &
  nor25 (background: norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]};   II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1) \\
  MDH509 &
  nor104 (background: norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]};   II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1) \\
  MDH514 &
  nor109 (background: norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]};   II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1) \\
  MDH520 &
  nor115 (background: norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]};   II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1) \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 3.3}\\*
  MDH28 &
  trp-4(ot337);otIs259 \\
  MDH488 &
  cni-1 (tm4274);trp-4(ot337);otIs259{[}dat-1::gfp{]} \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 3.4}\\*
  MDH492 &
  nor25;norEx131{[}cni-1;myo-2::mcherry;rol-6{]}(background:norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1) \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 3.5}\\*
  MDH496 &
  cni-1(crispr\_nor25);norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]};   II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1 \\
  MDH841 &
  sec-24.2(crispr\_nor104) wt   PAM;norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1 \\
  MDH597 &
  sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus silent   mut{]});norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3)   III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1 \\
  MDH905 &
  cni-1(crispr\_nor140{[}nor115 plus silent   mut{]});norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3)   III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1) \\
  \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 4.4}\\*
  MDH590 &
  norEx150{[}pdat::cni-1::UTR, ccRFP{]};   cni-1(crispr\_nor25);norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3)   III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1 \\
  MDH634 &
  norEx177{[}Pdat-1::SEC-24.2::mKate::UTR + ccRFP{]};   sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus silent   mut{]});norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3)   III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1 Line 1 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 4.7}\\*
  MDH732 &
  norEx215{[}pdat::sec-24.2(Ex2-4)SENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR +   pdat::sec-24.2(Ex4-2)ANTISENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR + ccRFP{]};   norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1   line 1 \\
  MDH733 &
  norEx216{[}pdat::sec-24.2(Ex2-4)SENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR +   pdat::sec-24.2(Ex4-2)ANTISENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR + ccRFP{]};   norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1   line 2 \\
  MDH719 &
  norEx213{[}pdat::mkate::UTR + ccRFP{]};   norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1   line 1 \\
  MDH720 &
  norEx214{[}pdat::mkate::UTR + ccRFP{]};   norSci1\_{[}dat1::Trp-4(d)\_unc-119{]}; II;unc-119(ed3) III;trp-4(ot337)I;vtIs1   line 2 \\
  MDH739 &
  norEx218{[}pdat::sec-24.2(Ex2-4)SENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR +   pdat::sec-24.2(Ex4-2)ANTISENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR + ccRFP{]};vtIs1 line 1 \\
  MDH740 &
  norEx219{[}pdat::sec-24.2(Ex2-4)SENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR +   pdat::sec-24.2(Ex4-2)ANTISENSE::SL2::mkate::UTR + ccRFP{]};vtIs1 line 2 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 4.8}\\*
  MDH570 &
  norEx139{[}Pdat1::cni-1,rol-6,ccRFP{]};trp-4(ot337);otIs259 \\
  MDH675 &
  norEx209{[}Pdat-1::SEC-24.2::mKate::UTR +   ccGFP{]};trp-4(ot337);otIs259, Line 1 \\
  MDH673 &
  norEx207{[}Pdat-1::SEC-24.2::mKate::UTR +   ccGFP{]};norEx139{[}Pdat1::cni-1,rol-6,ccRFP{]};trp-4(ot337);otIs259, Line 2 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 4.9}\\*
  TQ420 &
  trp-4(sy695);XuEx542{[}Ptrp-4::trp-4::yfp + Podr-1::RFP{]} \\*
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 4.10, 4.11, 4.12, 4.13}\\
  MDH698 &
  norIs1{[}pdat::TRP-4::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx, Line 1 \\
  MDH699 &
  norIs2{[}pdat::TRP-4::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx, Line 2 \\
  MDH705 &
  norIs2{[}pdat::TRP-4::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx;   cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
  MDH742 &
  norIs1{[}pdat::TRP-4::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx;nor104 \\
  MDH707 &
  norIs1{[}pdat::TRP-4::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx;   sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus silent mut{]}) \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 4.14}\\*
  PY6100 &
  oyIs59{[}osm-6::osm-6::gfp{]} \\
  MDH886 &
  oyIs59{[}osm-6::osm-6::gfp{]};cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
  MDH887 &
  oyIs59{[}osm-6::osm-6::gfp{]};nor104 \\
  MDH885 &
  oyIs59{[}osm-6::osm-6::gfp{]};sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus   silent mut{]}) \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 4.158}\\*
  MDH893 &
  vtIs1{[}dat-1::gfp{]};him-8(e1489); pha-1(e2123) III;   otIs393{[}ift-20p::NLS::tagRFP + pha-1(+){]} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 4.16}\\*
  MDH911 &
  Y110A7A.20(ok3191) I;norIs2{[}pdat::TRP-4::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx,   Line 2 \\
  MDH1037 &
  unc-101(sy108) I;norIs1{[}pdat::TRP-4::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 4.18}\\*
  MDH26 &
  trp-4(ot337);vtIs1 V \\
  MDH938 &
  trp-4(ot337) I;vtIs1;him-8(e1489) IV?;Y110A7A.20(ok3191) I \\
  MDH969 &
  unc-101(sy108) I;trp-4(ot337) I;vtIs1 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 5.1}\\*
  MDH932 &
  kyEx576(rol-6+ocr-2::GFP::ocr-2);norIs32{[}Pcni-1::CNI-1::mKate\_HygR;ccGFP{]},   Line 1/xxx \\
  MDH933 &
  kyEx576(rol-6+ocr-2::GFP::ocr-2);norEX180{[}Psec-24.2::SEC-24.2::mKate::UTRsec-24.2   + ccRFP{]} Line 1 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 5.2, 5.3}\\*
  CX5448 &
  kyEx576(rol-6+ocr-2::GFP::ocr-2) \\
  MDH903 &
  kyEx576(rol-6+ocr-2::GFP::ocr-2);cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
  MDH904 &
  kyEx576(rol-6+ocr-2::GFP::ocr-2);nor104 \\
  MDH902 &
  kyEx576(rol-6+ocr-2::GFP::ocr-2);sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109   plus silent mut{]}) \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 5.4}\\*
  MDH936 &
  norIs33{[}Posm-9::OSM-9::GFP +   ccRFP{]}/xxx;norIs32{[}Pcni-1::CNI-1::mKate\_HygR;ccGFP{]}, Line 1/xxx \\
  MDH937 &
  norIs33{[}Posm-9::OSM-9::GFP +   ccRFP{]}/xxx;norEX180{[}Psec-24.2::SEC-24.2::mKate::UTRsec-24.2 + ccRFP{]} Line 1 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 5.5, 5.6}\\*
  MDH888 &
  norIs33{[}Posm-9::OSM-9::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx \\
  MDH895 &
  norIs33{[}Posm-9::OSM-9::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx;cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
  MDH897 &
  norIs33{[}Posm-9::OSM-9::GFP + ccRFP{]}/xxx;nor104 \\
  MDH896 &
  norIs33{[}Posm-9::OSM-9::GFP +   ccRFP{]}/xxx;sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus silent mut{]}); \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 5.7}\\*
  MDH934 &
  mysIs1{[}PKD2::GFP+ccGFP{]}pkd-2(sy606)IV;him-5(e1490)   V;norIs32{[}Pcni-1::CNI-1::mKate\_HygR;ccGFP{]}, Line 1/xxx \\
  MDH935 &
  mysIs1{[}PKD2::GFP+ccGFP{]}pkd-2(sy606)IV;him-5(e1490)   V;norEX180{[}Psec-24.2::SEC-24.2::mKate::UTRsec-24.2 + ccRFP{]} Line 1 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 5.8, 5.10}\\*
  PT443 &
  mysIs1{[}PKD2::GFP+ccGFP{]}pkd-2(sy606)IV;him-5(e1490) V \\
  MDH908 &
  mysIs1{[}PKD2::GFP+ccGFP{]}pkd-2(sy606)IV;cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
  MDH909 &
  mysIs1{[}PKD2::GFP+ccGFP{]}pkd-2(sy606)IV;him-5(e1490)   V;sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus silent mut{]}) \\
  MDH910 &
  mysIs1{[}PKD2::GFP+ccGFP{]}pkd-2(sy606)IV;him-5(e1490) V;nor104 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 5.11}\\*
  MDH663 &
  norEx199{[}pdat-1::DAT-1::GFP::UTR + ccRFP{]}, Line 1 \\
  MDH677 &
  norEx210{[}pdat-1::DAT-1::GFP::UTR + ccRFP{]};cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
  MDH757 &
  norEx220{[}Pdat-1::GFP::DAT-1::UTR + ccRFP{]};nor104 \\
  MDH678 &
  norEx211{[}pdat-1::DAT-1::GFP::UTR +   ccRFP{]};sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus silent mut{]}) \\
  MDH666 &
  norEx201{[}Pasic-1::ASIC-1::GFP::UTR+ ccRFP{]}, Line 1 \\
  MDH683 &
  norEx201{[}Pasic-1::ASIC-1::GFP::UTR+ ccRFP{]};cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
  MDH756 &
  norEx201{[}Pasic-1::ASIC-1::GFP::UTR+ ccRFP{]};nor104 \\
  MDH684 &
  norEx201{[}Pasic-1::ASIC-1::GFP::UTR+   ccRFP{]};sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus silent mut{]}) \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Figure 5.12}\\*
  MDH730 &
  zdIs5(I) \\
  MDH241 &
  zdIs5(I);mec-4(u231)(X) \\
  MDH728 &
  zdIs5(I);mec-4(u231)(X);cni-1(crispr\_nor25) \\
  MDH759 &
  zdIs5(I);mec-4(u231)(X);nor104 \\
  MDH729 &
  zdIs5(I);mec-4(u231)(X);sec-24.2(crispr\_nor120{[}nor109 plus   silent mut{]}) \\
  \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

---

Update regarding caption placement:

Following typographical conventions, a table's caption should be placed above the table. I thus suggest the following:

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{\quad}l>{\RaggedRight}X}
  \caption{the caption text}\label{key}\\
  \toprule
  Strain &  Genotype \\
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \caption{the caption text - continued from previous page}\\
  \toprule
  Strain &  Genotype \\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{continued on following page}\\
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
```

If you insist on placing the caption below the table on the last page, you can use

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{\quad}l>{\RaggedRight}X}
  \toprule
  Strain &  Genotype \\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \bottomrule
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \caption{the caption text}\label{key}\\
  \endlastfoot
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that was very useful. Just a small follow up, I tried to add a caption at the very end of the table, with `\caption{bla bla}` , but I can't manage to have the caption **after** the bottomrule, any ideas?

Comment: @LourdesRiquelme: I have updated my answer accordingly.